# Get rows with more then a word with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I get all the rows of a table that have one word, and the ones that have more then a word:

For example take the following records:

```
CARROCARIA PINTURA
VEICULOS ALUGUER
VEICULOS ELETRICOS
SERVICOS RAPIDOS
VEICULOS COMERCIAIS
ELETRICIDADE
VIDROS
```

I get with query 1:

```
ELETRICIDADE
VIDROS
```

I get with Query 2:

```
CARROCARIA PINTURA
VEICULOS ALUGUER
VEICULOS ELETRICOS
SERVICOS RAPIDOS
VEICULOS COMERCIAIS
```

Thanks.

Comment: But **ELETRICIDADE VIDROS** if is a one row, then have two words...i do not undestand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One word

```
select * from tablename where fieldname not like '% %'
```

multiple words

```
select * from tablename where fieldname like '% %'
```

**EDIT**

if leading / trailing spaces could be an issue, you can use something like

```
select * from tablename where ltrim(rtrim(fieldname)) like '% %'
```

Comment: Beware trailing/leading spaces

Comment: Maybe you can help me on this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17634090/create-related-records-based-on-string-in-sql-server